# Как в Slick js отобразить половину следующего слайда?

Tags: css, slick.js

Как в Slick Js отобразить половину следующего слайда? 
[Песочница CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBvQbG)

Вариант сладу задать 500px а контейнеру 1000px не работает

```
   <body>
    <div class="your-class">
      <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    </body>

<style>
    .your-class {
      display: block;
      width: 1000px;
    }
    .your-class div {
      width: 500px;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.your-class').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 1000,
            variableWidth: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для того что бы отобразить часть следующего слайда достаточно добавить в CSS следующие стили:

```
.slick-list{
    padding:0 20% 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в код вызова:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.your-class').slick({
            centerMode: true
        });
    });
</script>
```